# How to implement variables in a structure in c?

Tags: c, variables, structure

*THIS IS NOT THE COMPLETE PROGRAM*

```
struct p
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
};
void main()
{
int op,i,j,to,from,a,b,c;
struct p pr[3];
clrscr();
for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    pr[i].a=0;
    pr[i].b=0;
    pr[i].c=0;
    printf("P%d %d %d %d\n",i,pr[i].a,pr[i].b,pr[i].c);
}
do{

printf("\nEnter the option you want to execute:\n1. Internal Event\n2. Send Message \n3. Exit \n\n");
scanf("%d",&op);


switch(op)
{
    case 1:
    printf("\nEnter the process for which the internal event takes place: ");
    scanf("%d",&j);
```

Values of j will vary from 1 to 3
What I want to do here is:
if j=1,
pr[1].a=pr[1].a+1;
Instead of implementing a switch case for j, I would like to automatically update the value for 
pr[j]a/b/c

can someone help be out with it.
PS: I am trying to implement a C program for Vector Clocks

Comment: Note that array indices start at 0, not at one (it also means you have a bug when you iterate i=1; i<4; i++). You can change the struct to an array, so you have int pr[3][3]. Now you can index as e.g. pr[j-1][j-1]++; (Note how I subtract 1 from j to get at the array indices).

Comment: the loop works fine in another program that I coded. Is there no way to implement it using structures? I thought about using 2 dimensional arrays, but it gets messy in the latter half of the program.

Comment: a) That the loop works fine is because it overwrites c, b and a on the stack. You have a bug. Indices start at zero. See my above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the struct doesn't change, it is equivalent to an array of ints. Then you can use a union and use whatever is prettiest:

```
typedef union uBoth {
    struct
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    } p;
    int q[3];
};

void main()
{
    int op,i,j,to,from,a,b,c;
    union uBoth pr[3];

    clrscr();
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++)
            pr[i].q[j]= 0;
        printf("P%d %d %d %d\n",i+1, pr[i].p.a, pr[i].p.b, pr[i].p.c);
    }
    do {
        printf("\nEnter the option you want to execute:\n1. Internal Event\n2. Send Message \n3. Exit \n\n");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter the process for which the internal event takes place: ");
                scanf("%d",&j);
                pr[j-1].p.a= 1;
        }
    } while(1);
}
```